# Oracle 11g ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info

Tags: oracle, aix

I've been having this problem for more than 4 days, I've tried to fix it but it persists!

The content of the log file `$ORACLE_HOME/log/diag/rdbms/<sid>/<SID>/trace/alert_SID.log` is:

```
SQL > ALTER DATABASE MOUNT;
```

> ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
>   ORA-00202: control file: '/intradayv3/position/control1/POSCTL1.ctl'
>   ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
>   IBM AIX RISC System/6000 Error: 2: No such file or directory
>   Additional information: 3
>   ORA-205 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT...
>   Fri Apr 03 12:24:44 2015
>   Checker run found 1 new persistent data failures

Comment: Does the file `/intradayv3/position/control1/POSCTL1.ctl` exist?

Comment: Did you have more than one copy of the control file?  Do you back up your database with RMAN?  If the answer to at least one of these questions is 'yes' then you can recover your database.  Look at [the advice listed here](http://www.f1oracle.com/oracle/recover-oracle-database-from-a-corrupt-or-missing-control-file/).  If you have a manual backup of the control file you can restore from that instead; the Oracle docs has [the relevant steps here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/osadvsce.htm#BRADV90043)

Comment: Since when is this error occurring? What were the recent changes? Did you change any permissions at OS level? Did you accidentally delete any files?  Get the control files name and locations, copy the missing one and rename it to appropriate name and start the database.

Comment: Thank you all! Bob Jarvis, no the control file doesn't exist, I suppose that oracle should manage its creation!

Comment: As a last resort you can create the control file manually.  Check the (SQL Reference for details)[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5003.htm#SQLRF01203]

Comment: APC, no I have no control file. Thank you, I see it now.

Comment: You should be able to copy and rename the required control file.

Comment: Lalit Kumar B, no I don't remember that I delete or change something of that!

Comment: If you lost all controlfiles and your datafiles have different SCN written in their headers, then you probably should restore database from backup.

Answer (score 0):

check init.ora file(spfile.ora) and check ALL controlfiles listed here. There should be at least three of them. Then exclude the missiin one form the list and try to start the database. You should also check sizes and dates of all control files.

Your goal is to find at least one usable copy of controlfile to start the database.

```
create pfile='/tmp/init.ora' from spfile;
```

then edit this init.ora file.

```
 startup database pfile='/tmp/init.ora' nomount;
 alter database mount;
 alter database open;
```

You have to sync init.ora with valid controlfiles you have on the disk.
Check their permissions, sizes, modification dates.

Comment: Thank you ibre5041 for your answer. This is what I do exactly:
sqlplus sys as sysdba
startup pfile='<initSID_path>/initSID.ora' nomount
The instance is started now, we see the SGA.
Then I do :
shutdown immediate
After that, I try to restart the instance with the "mount" mode : 
startup pfile='<initSID_path>/initSID.ora'
I get the error above!